# Python looping in a loop

Tags: python

Im looking to iterate through a list of servers and usernames and passwords.

The idea is to take a username password pair and try each with a server from a server list. Seems simple enough, however I cant work out how to go through the server list and the userpass list.

Maybe create a file containing the username and pass with each server(1 server per line)?

Below is the code I have gotten so far. Capture the list of users+passwords from one file. Grab list of servers from another. Split the username pass pairs into a dictionary. Stick the servers in a list removing the \n (newline).

I try iterate through each in the `def keycmd` function but as you can see it only takes first username password and iterates the servers.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

**EXAMPLE CLI & OUTPUT**

```
c:\Python27>python rdpcheck.py -u userpass.txt -s servers.txt

#This output is based on 1 user in the userlist

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.122 User1 Passw1

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.111 User1 Passw1

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.112 User1 Passw1

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.113 User1 Passw1

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.114 User1 Passw1

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.115 User1 Passw1

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.116 User1 Passw1

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.117 User1 Passw1

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
192.168.1.118 User1 Passw1
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Valid user credentials used to test RDP access to list of RDP enabled servers. credentials against a list of servers

Usage:
  rdpcheck.py (-u <FILE>) (-s <FILE>)
  rdpcheck.py -h | --help
  rdpcheck.py --version

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  -u --user=FILE
  -s --server=FILE
  """
from docopt import docopt
import subprocess

def getuserpass(userpass):
        nlist = {}
        with open(userpass, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                        k = line.split()
                        nlist[k[0]] = k[1]
        return nlist

def getservers(servers):
        slist = open(servers).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '') for s in slist]

def rdpcall(userpass, servers):
        print "This is doing stuff"
        subprocess.call(['mstsc'])

def keycmd(listuserpass, servers):
        nlist = listuserpass

        for username, password in nlist.iteritems():

                for server in servers:
                        print server, username, password
                        print subprocess.check_output("cmdkey /generic:TERMSERV/%s /user:%s /pass:%s"), server, username, password

if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')

        returned_userlist = getuserpass(arguments['--user'])
        returned_servers = getservers(arguments['--server'])
        print keycmd(returned_userlist, returned_servers)
```

Comment: You have a `return cmdout` in your inner for loop. Hence, that loop will never go to its next iteration, nor will the outer loop. You'll probably want to store all those `cmdout` results in some list or dict, and return that at the end of the `keycmd` function.

Comment: I dont really need to return the cmdout that was only for testing. As long as the cmdkey addes the users thats fine the next step is it call rdp, but of course i want to get the `def keycmd` function working first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the setup. Why do you have a list of username, password pairs that you don't know the server they belong to? (Sorry about the logic of the sentence)

That being said, your code seems to do mostly the right thing. (I have some non-functional quibbles, but nothing that should change the behavior of the code.) What output are you getting? Could you provide example input files and example output?

By the way: keycmd doesn't return anything. What are you trying to print?

Comment: Apologies, let me explain. I work as an Ethical hacker, and during a job recently I was able to compromise various users credentials but couldnt access any systems via psexec etc so was left with a list of servers with rdp enabled and loads of useraccounts. So i had to manually try all. Im looking to create a tool to help me out next time ;)

Comment: @marky1991 , im printing it to see the output from cmdkey command. (Apologies if you see oddities in the code im very new to coding ^_^, started reading a book on python about 2 weeks ago) The print wont stay there its only for debugging atm.

Comment: Hmm seems I didnt actually have more than 1 user in the list lol, i started this last night at about 00:00 and went to bed at about 03:00 thinking i got stuck. rofl its working now ive added more users :P

Comment: The point of the print thing is that `print keygen(whatever)` is never going to print anything other than `None` since it doesn't actually ever return anything.